# Flutter catch RenderOverflow

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

Is it possible in Flutter to catch the RenderOverflow error?
I want to display an other widget if this error occurse.

I tried the usage of try/catch but it doesnt't work.

I'm looking forward to your responses.

Comment: The ideal solution is to fix the render flow errors in your UI. You know what data you are expecting, and how the widgets will look, and accordingly create paths for how they should appear, without overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch this error, what you need to do to avoid this issue is using `SingleChildScrollView`, and that is the best solution.